# Need Help on SQL joins in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for examples for all Joins in Google BigQuery. Also need examples for all subqueries, String functions. Can we create a stored procedure and refresh a table in Google BigQuery?

Comment: This is a really broad question. Can you provide more details around what you are stuck on, specifically with some SQL examples that you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery does not have notion of stored procedure

You can see documentation and examples for JOIN types [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types)
Also for [String functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string-functions)

Comment: Trying ti use FULL OUTER JOIN but getting this error. Error: 5.1 - 7.37: FULL OUTER and RIGHT OUTER joins are only supported with JOIN EACH

Comment: turn on #standardSQL for better results!